# Why is my implementation of CSP returning errors?

Tags: php, security, web, header, content-security-policy

I'm trying to add CSP to a page of a PHP application but I'm getting the error

```
The Content-Security-Policy directive name 'script‑src' contains one or more invalid characters. Only ASCII alphanumeric characters or dashes '-' are allowed in directive names.
```

This is how I'm trying to implement CSP

```
<?php
// forum.php: Forum...
header("Content-Security-Policy: script‑src self;default‑src self;media‑src none;img‑src self;");
?>
            <h1>Welcome to your forum</h1>
            <h2>Post a message bellow:</h2>
            <form name=posttoforumform method=POST action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?>">
                <!--<p><input type="text" name="user_name" size="20"></p> -->
                <p><textarea rows="5" cols="80" name="input_from_form" size="20"></textarea></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit_button" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></p>
            </form>

<?php
// Grab inputs
$inputfromform = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["input_from_form"]);
$showonlyuser =  $_REQUEST["show_only_user"];

if ($inputfromform  <> "") {    
    //$pattern = "<script>";
    //if(!preg_match($pattern, $inputfromform)){
        $query = "INSERT INTO forum_table(poster_name, comment, date) VALUES ('".
        $user->username . "', '".
        $inputfromform  . "', " .
        " now() )";
        $result = execute_query($query);
    /*}else{        
        echo '<script>alert("Nice try! Your Cross XSS has not been succcessfully delivered :P")</script>';
    }*/ 
}

?>
```

I also tried to implement CSP by using .httaccess file like this

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "
    default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self';
    img-src 'self';
"
```

But I get this error

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `self` must be enclosed in single quotes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/Sources#sources

Comment: @ChrisHaas it is

Comment: According to this line, the word `self` it is **not** enclosed in quotes: `header("Content-Security-Policy: script‑src self;default‑src self;media‑src none;img‑src self;");`

Answer (score 2):

There are many variations of very similar characters that look like dash (em dash, en dash, minus sign, hyphen etc.). The error message states "Only ASCII alphanumeric characters or dashes '-' are allowed in directive names." Now take the - character from the error message and search for it on this page and you will see that in your line

```
header("Content-Security-Policy: script‑src self;default‑src self;media‑src none;img‑src self;");
```

only the dashes in "Content-Security-Policy" match, the ones you use in the directives are charecters that look the same. Such changes to characters often happens when word processors handle dashes. If your code has been copied to e.g. MS Word and back your dashes are no longer the same.

You also seem to define two Content-Security-Policies. This means that everything need to pass both policies, another policy can only make it stricter.

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be to use a class to generate the proper CSP headers. Look at [this example](https://github.com/theking2/php-csp-builder)